# How to target child element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How to target the img element in JavaScript to change img src.

```html
<body>
 <div class="cover">
  <img src="img.jpg" width="60" height="60">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: And what did you try before coming here ?

Comment: This is a really basic question, you should try to google it first.

Answer (score 2):

```
document.querySelector(".cover img").src = "/test/test.jpg";
```

please visit [HTML DOM querySelector() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp) for more information (compatibility, ...)

Answer (score 0):

`element.querySelector('img')` can get you there as well.

```js
var cover = document.getElementsByClassName('cover')[0],
    img   = cover.querySelector('img');
img.src = 'http://placehold.it/60x60';
```

```html
<div class="cover">
    <img src="img.jpg" width="60" height="60">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First select you parent class and then using that select your child element.

```
var a = document.querySelector(".cover");
var b = a.querySelector("img");
b.style.width = "500px";
b.style.height = "500px";
b.src = "https://source.unsplash.com/category/nature";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to support legacy browsers you can do with with **document.querySelector**:

```
document.querySelector(".cover img").setAttribute("src", "anotherimage.png");
```